# How can you print all the possible commands of a unix command line tool?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line-arguments

I want to see a list of all possible options for a specific command line tool. The `--help` option can be useful, but might not include all the options and sometimes you just need a list instead of a detailed description. Basically the bash equivalent of `dir()` in python.

For example:

The command `python --help` pulls up a description of options/arguments. However it doesn't include options such as `python --version`. Does bash have a way to check this?

Comment: You can't, because the options aren't something that exist in a queryable form; the program has to be written to *report* on what options it will work on.

Comment: I think you're confused. By "bash function" perhaps you mean any command line utility you can run from a terminal? if so, they're not part of bash they're standalone applications written by various authors that _happen_ to use the same flag `--help` to print some useful info. `man` is the typical *nix utility for getting more verbose info on a command otherwise search the internet for docs on the command

Comment: @stacksonstacks Yes I wasn't sure what to call it, but I've updated the question to say 'command line tool' instead.

Comment: another useful tool is [tldr](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to get help on.

For an executable like python your best bet is the man page. This is only really available on Unix though. eg.

```
man python
```

This brings up a screen that looks like:

```
PYTHON(1)                   General Commands Manual                  PYTHON(1)

NAME
       python  - an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming lan‐
       guage

SYNOPSIS
       python [ -B ] [ -d ] [ -E ] [ -h ] [ -i ] [ -m module-name ]
              [ -O ] [ -OO ] [ -R ] [ -Q argument ] [ -s ] [ -S ] [ -t ] [ -u ]
              [ -v ] [ -V ] [ -W argument ] [ -x ] [ -3 ] [ -?  ]
              [ -c command | script | - ] [ arguments ]

DESCRIPTION
       Python is an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming lan‐
       guage that ...

COMMAND LINE OPTIONS
       ...

       -V ,  --version
              Prints the Python version number of the executable and exits.
       ...
```

This uses a program called `less` to display the information. You can scroll with the arrow keys and quit with q. There are more commands available in less. Type `man less` to find out more.

If you're looking for help on a bash builtin (eg. `echo`) try the bash builtin `help` eg.

```
help echo
```